# Doesn't Monaco Editor support XML language by default?

Tags: xml, visual-studio-code, monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco

I am trying to use Monaco Editor for XML language, but XML string is not getting formatted while the editor instance is being rendered, whereas its working fine for JSON.

I also don't find "Format Document" option in Context Menu of Editor(if it is opened with XML language). 
Does Monaco editor support XML formatting by default?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  At least provide the code you have tried.  FYI, XML **is** supported by default with Monaco.

Also, you are asking two different questions:

1) does Monaco support XML files and
2) Does Monaco by default provide an XML formatter.

Answer (score 7):

It appears that Monaco Editor doesn't format xml by default. A colleague of mine - [@thewahome](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7035437/thewahome), had to write code to format the xml. If you're interested on how to format xml the following snippet will help.

```
function formatXml(xml: any) {
  const PADDING = ' '.repeat(2);
  const reg = /(>)(<)(\/*)/g;
  let pad = 0;

  xml = xml.replace(reg, '$1\r\n$2$3');

  return xml.split('\r\n').map((node: any, index: number) => {
    let indent = 0;
    if (node.match(/.+<\/\w[^>]*>$/)) {
      indent = 0;
    } else if (node.match(/^<\/\w/) && pad > 0) {
      pad -= 1;
    } else if (node.match(/^<\w[^>]*[^\/]>.*$/)) {
      indent = 1;
    } else {
      indent = 0;
    }

    pad += indent;

    return PADDING.repeat(pad - indent) + node;
  }).join('\r\n');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The support for XML in Monaco is strange. As far as I know, there is no XML formatting enabled. I would suggest **formatting XML only once on your backend** and sending it already formatted. Client-side formatting can be a **potential bottleneck** in your app if you edit large texts.

But if you still prefer client-side formatting, it can be done using HTML formatter as suggested in this [GitHub comment](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/1509#issuecomment-864441191).

Actions **Format Document** and **Reindent Lines** will be enabled with the following configuration. Monaco will even follow XML indention as you type.

You can play around with this in [Monaco editor playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html). (just copy, paste, run):

```js
// Monaco doesn't support XML formatting. But it's possible to use HTML formatting.
// https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/1509#issuecomment-864441191
monaco.languages.html.registerHTMLLanguageService(
    "xml",
    {
        format: {
            wrapLineLength: 0,
            preserveNewLines: false,
        }
    },
    { documentFormattingEdits: true },
);

const editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
    value: "<group><content><value text=\"Text\"></value><!--\nPress Ctrl + Shift + F\nto reformat this XML\n--></content></group>",
    language: "xml",
    tabSize: 2,
    autoIndent: "full",
    detectIndentation: true,
    formatOnType: true,
    formatOnPaste: true,
});

monaco.languages.setLanguageConfiguration("xml", {
    "indentationRules": {
        "increaseIndentPattern": new RegExp("<(?!\\?|[^>]*\\/>)([-_.A-Za-z0-9]+)(?=\\s|>)\\b[^>]*>(?!.*<\\/\\1>)|<!--(?!.*-->)|\\{[^}\"']*$"),
        "decreaseIndentPattern": new RegExp("^\\s*(<\\/(?!html)[-_.A-Za-z0-9]+\\b[^>]*>|-->|})"),
    },
});

// Format document and reindned lines with Ctrl + Shift + F
editor.addAction({
    id: "formatDocumentAndReindentLines",
    label: "Format Document and Reindent Lines",
    keybindings: [monaco.KeyMod.CtrlCmd | monaco.KeyMod.Shift | monaco.KeyCode.KeyF],
    run: async (editor) => {
        await editor.getAction("editor.action.formatDocument").run();
        // Reindent is here for multiline comments
        return editor.getAction("editor.action.reindentlines").run();
    },
});
```

`indentationRules` are borrowed from [vscode HTML extension configuration](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/html/language-configuration.json) and simplified. More information about it [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-configuration-guide#indentation-rules).