# Auto-format XML in Monaco Editor

Tags: angular, monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco, ngx-monaco-editor

I use the [ngx-monaco-editor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-monaco-editor) package in my Angular app to use [Monaco Editor](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/). I'm trying to set auto-formatting for XML content.

### Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.scss']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  editorOptions = {
    language: 'xml',
    autoIndent: 'full',
    formatOnPaste: true,
    formatOnType: true,
    automaticLayout: true
  };
  code: string= '<parent><child></child></parent>';
...
```

### Template

```
      <ngx-monaco-editor id="content" formControlName="content" class="editor"
                         [options]="editorOptions"
                         [(ngModel)]="code">
      </ngx-monaco-editor>
```

### Actual Result

[image]

### Expected Result

[image]

How to achieve the expected result?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@materia-ui/ngx-monaco-editor Try this!

Comment: Possible a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57039218/doesnt-monaco-editor-support-xml-language-by-default

Answer (score 1):

You can use the editor init event & trigger the format options manually

```js
public initEditor(editor: any): void {
    if (editor) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        editor.getAction('editor.action.formatDocument').run();
      }, 100);
    }
  }
```

```html
<ngx-monaco-editor class="editor" [options]="editorOptions" [(ngModel)]="code" (onInit)="initEditor($event)"></ngx-monaco-editor>
```